# Error al alinear formulario dentro de un div

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de alinear un formulario dentro de un `div` pero como se puede ver en el resultado, queda situado a la derecha y no se como hacer para que quede centrado.

```css
.container-1 {margin: 0 auto; width: 50rem;} /* 800 */
.bg-2 {background-color: #f6f9fc;}

.bd-example {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-width: .2rem;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1 bg-2">
<div class="bd-example">
<form action="" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="post" placeholder="Post"></textarea>
</div>

<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiza lo deseas centrar el contendido.

```css
.container-1 {margin: 0 auto; width: 50rem;} /* 800 */
.bg-2 {background-color: #f6f9fc;}

.bd-example {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    
}
form{
width:60%;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .370rem;
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1 bg-2">
 <div class="bd-example">
  <form action="" method="post">

   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
   </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="post" placeholder="Post">       </textarea>
   </div>

   <button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Lo hice utilizando flexbox, seria bueno que leas un poco sobre eso.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando clases de bootstrap, por lo que intuyo lo estas usando. De ser así, te faltan clases que te ayudan con la alineación y el responsive, por ejemplo: `.row y .col-12`

Puedes encontrar toda la información de [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp) y cómo utilizar la grilla.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando.

Saludos

```css
.bg-blue{
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 p-3 mt-5 bg-blue">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero estoy tratando de hacer esto fuera de bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el siguiente CSS

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Estas aplicando un `width: 100%;`, ademas agregando un `padding: .375rem .75rem;` y un `border: 1px solid #ced4da;`. Eso hace que tu elemento mida mas del 100% del ancho (100%+.75rem+.75rem+1px+1px) por eso se sale de la caja. Puedes utilizar la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box;` para hacer que tu padding y border sean tenido encuenta dentro de la caja y no sumado al width.